# Thread safe singleton with async operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety, singleton, ninject

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application using Ninject for DI. I have a message that is displayed at the top of every page. The message is retrieved from a web service, using an async operation. The message itself is small and updated infrequently, so I want to cache it in memory.

I've created a simple service that is configured as DI singleton. I had a nice thing going `ReaderWriterLock`, but that doesn't support async. So I've tried recreate the same thing with `SemaphoreSlim`. This is what I've got:

```
    public class ExampleService {

        private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
        private DateTime? lastAccess = null;
        private string cachedMessage = null;

        public async Task<string> GetMessageAsync() {
            if (lastAccess.HasValue && lastAccess.Value > DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1)) {
                return cachedMessage;
            }

            var writeable = semaphore.CurrentCount == 1;

            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            try {
                if (writeable) {
                    // Do async stuff
                }
            }
            finally {
                semaphore.Release();
            }

            return cachedMessage;
        }

        ~ExampleService() {
            if (semaphore != null) semaphore.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

The goal is to have all calls wait until `cacheMessage` is populated, then give it to everyone. The problem with my solution is that once the write call has completed, all the waiting reads are effectively stuck in a queue being released one by one, while new reads get to jump the queue completely.

What is a better way of doing this?

*Update*

Based on this [post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/EyesWideOpenCorrectCachingIsAlwaysHard.aspx), a lot of people appear to advocate just using [LazyCache](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache). Making the implementation:

```
    public class ExampleService {

        private readonly IAppCache cache;

        public ExampleService(IAppCache cache) {
            this.cache = cache;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetMessageFromServerAsync() {
            // result = async stuff
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetMessageAsync() {
            return await cache.GetOrAddAsync("MessageKey", GetMessageFromServerAsync);
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no need to use finalizer in your code, since it doesn't have any unmanaged resources

Comment: What is your question now? Is there any alternative to LazyCache? Is there any other sync primitive, which might be useful for your solution? BTW, there is an [async readwritelock](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncReaderWriterLock) implementation written by Stephen Cleary

Comment: @PeterCsala: I'm on the verge of answering my own question. I had wanted to avoid a package, but also not spend a lot of time on reinventing the wheel. I think `LazyCache` is going to work me, but will not 'answer' the question until it's tested. In the meantime other suggestions welcome. Looks like your suggestion would have been a perfect drop in replacement for my original implementation, oh well!

Comment: Using the property [`SemaphoreSlim.CurrentCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.currentcount) is usually an indicator of a race condition. This property or generally useful only for logging purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [post](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/EyesWideOpenCorrectCachingIsAlwaysHard.aspx), a lot of people appear to advocate just using [LazyCache](https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache). Making the implementation:

```
public class ExampleService {

    private readonly IAppCache cache;

    public ExampleService(IAppCache cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetMessageFromServerAsync() {
        // result = async stuff
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetMessageAsync() {
        return await cache.GetOrAddAsync("MessageKey", GetMessageFromServerAsync);
    }

}
```